# In R, why does map make the wrong plot, but the same code works when I do not map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, r-factor

I want to map a ggplot over a pre-set vector of x variables. The code does generate the plots, but it looks wrong when I use map()--it collapses all the factors into one group. However, this does not happen when I do not use map. Why is this happening? I explicitly call for these variables to be a factor:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)


data('mtcars')

#Define x variables to iterate over
x_variables <- c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")

#Create function

make_chart <- function(data, x, y){
  
  require(stringr)
  
  x_title <- str_to_title(rlang::as_name(enquo(x)))
  
  ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor({{x}}), y = {{y}})) +
    geom_col() +
    ggtitle(paste0("Number of ", x_title, " by MPG")) +
    xlab(x_title)
  
}

#This runs--but collapses results across factors
  map(.x = x_variables,
      ~mtcars %>%
        make_chart(x = .x, y = mpg))
  
  #This looks right
  make_chart(data = mtcars, x = gear, y = mpg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `do.call` here, ensuring to wrap your `.x` variable in `ensym`:

```r
plot_list <- map(.x = x_variables,
                 ~ do.call(make_chart, 
                    list(data = mtcars, x = rlang::ensym(.x), y = quote(mpg))))
```

So, for example, to plot all the generated images at once, we can do:

```r
library(patchwork)

(plot_list[[1]] + plot_list[[2]]) / 
  (plot_list[[3]] + plot_list[[4]] + plot_list[[5]])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you! Why does .x need to be wrapped in ensym() and mpg in quote(), and why does this only work within a do.call() command? Thank you again!

Comment: `do.call` allows you to "build" the call to your function. In your case, you would like the _symbols_  `cyl` and `mpg` passed as the arguments. The problem with calling your function directly instead of via `do.call` is that you are using non-standard evaluation of the `x` argument, so if you do `make_chart(x = .x, y = mpg)` then you are passing the symbol `.x` to the function. Using `rlang::ensym(.x)` inside `do.call` ensures that `.x` is substituted for the correct symbol.  Because we are using `do.call`, we also  need to wrap `mpg` in `quote` to prevent early evaluation of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

I think Allan Cameron's answer clearly illustrates and solves the problem (brilliant solution!), but another potential approach is to adjust `make_chart()`, rather than `map()`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data('mtcars')

#Define x variables to iterate over
x_variables <- c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")

#Create function
make_chart <- function(data, x, y){
  ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(!!sym(x)), y = !!enquo(y))) +
    geom_col() +
    ggtitle(paste0("Number of ", x, " by MPG")) +
    xlab(x)
}

map(.x = x_variables,
    ~mtcars %>%
      make_chart(x = .x, y = mpg))
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[4]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[5]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This is a lot 'simpler' than your example, and it may not translate to your real world scenario, but adapting this approach to suit your use-case might be worth investigating.

Comment: thank you! I like the simplicity of this solution--why does this work but mine does not?

Comment: It's hard to answer "why does this work?" without a lot of background info. To understand what's happening and why, I highly recommend Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R", chapters 18, 19, 20 ([free online](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html#expressions) or hard copy through [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Second-Chapman-Hall-CRC-dp-0815384572/dp/0815384572/ref=dp_ob_title_bk))